# Call to a member function set() on int

Tags: php, symfony, controller

So this bug randomly appears to me, 
For example my controller code was :

```
<?php 

namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class IndexController extends AbstractController 
{

    /**
     * @Route("/" , name="homepage")
     */
    public function homepage_function() 
    {
            dump("123");

            return $this->render("home/index.html.twig", [

            ] );
    }



}
```

I just added a die() after the dump("123), and that bug appears!

As soon as I Refresh the page, the bug is gone!

The code is perfectly fine, I just don't know what cause the bug!

Comment: Templates are cached. Try to clear cache after modifying a template.

Comment: Check the full error log, it should tell you where it is happening instead of guessing. There is no `->set()` in your code here, so it's happening somewhere else in the project.

Comment: So i need to php bin/console cache:clear each time i change a line in my code ? huh

Comment: if you're working with the `dev` environment (which is the default on local) you don't need to clear caches all the time. In `prod` you do need to clear the cache though. However, your error doesn't really match your code at all and might be completely unrelated ...

Comment: i am 100% sure that the code is perfectly fine , i just dont know what provoke the error , i dont dont what makes the error appear

Comment: since your code doesn't include a call `$somevar->set()` it's not really related. could you at least expand your error message to include the complete stack?